# How to add clickevent to retrieve input text and run function accordingly?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I am trying to add a onclick or click event that will allow someone to input a city and retrieve said city's weather information. I had added a event listener to the api function however it does not seem to work. Please help?

```js
 $.getJSON("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q="+City+"&appid=dc171ae0b3b507207c6605cbab0a5f98",
    function(data){
        
    console.log(data);

    var icon ="https://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.list[0].weather[0].icon +".png";
    var temp=Math.floor(data.list[0].main.temp);
    var weather=data.list[0].weather[0].main;
    var city=data.city.name;
    var date= data.list[0].dt_txt;
    var humidity=data.list[0].main.humidity;
    var wind=data.list[0].wind.speed;
    $(".icon").attr("src",icon);
    $(".weather").append(weather);
    $(".temp").append(temp);
    $(".city").append(city);    
    $(".date").append(date);
    $(".humidity").append(humidity);
    $(".wind").append(wind);
});
```

```css
/*Html & body theme*/

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{

    font-family:"lato",Arial,sans-serif;

}


body { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    color:black;   
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(8,19,114,1) 6%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 42%, rgba(231,246,246,1) 82%);  
    

}

/*container properties*/

.grid-container {
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
transition:0.3s;
}

.grid-container:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#box {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition:0.3s; 
    border-radius:5px;
    
}

#box{
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.grid-item-1{
    height: 150px;
    width:1880px;
    position:fixed;
    left:10px;
    top:20px;
    font-size:100px;
    text-align:center;
    
}

.grid-item-2{
    height: 600px;
    width:500px;
    position:fixed;
    left:10px;
    top:350px;
   
    
}
.grid-item-3{
    height: 300px;
    width:1370px;
    position:fixed;
    left:520px;
    top:180px;
    
    
}
.grid-item-4{
    height:450px;
    width:1370px;
    position:fixed;
    left:520px;
    top:500px;
    
    
}
.grid-item-5{
    height: 150px;
    width:500px;
    position:fixed;
    left:10px;
    top:180px;
    font-size: 30px;
    
}
/*Search Bar Properties*/
form.searchInput input[type=text] {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    background: #f1f1f1;
  }
  
  form.searchInput button {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #2196F3;
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-left: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  form.searchInput button:hover {
    background: #0b7dda;
  }
  
  form.searchInput::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
  }

  form.searchInput {
      top:30px;
      bottom:40px;
      position:relative;
    
  }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="WeatherDashboardStylesheet.css" type=text/CSS>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" 
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>WeatherDashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class ="grid-container">
       <div id="box" class="grid-item-1">
           WeatherDashboard ⛅ 

        </div>
       <div id="box" class="grid-item-2">
           Item 2

        </div>
       <div id="box" class="grid-item-3">
           Item 3

        </div>
       <div id="box" class="grid-item-4">
            <div id="display" class="display-box">
                <p class="city"></p>
                <img class="icon">
                <p class="date"></p>
                <p class="weather"></p>
                <p class="temp"></p>
                <p class="humidity"></p>
                <p class="wind"></p>
            </div>
        
       </div>
       <div id="box" class="grid-item-5">
           Search for a City:
          <form class="searchInput" style="margin:auto;max-width:300px">
            <input id=input class="input1" type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="search" value="">
            <button onclick="myfunction()" id="button" class="button1" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
          </form>

        </div>
   </div> 
   <script rel="Script" src="WeatherDashboardScript.js" type=text/javascript></script>
   <script src="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=chicago&appid=dc171ae0b3b507207c6605cbab0a5f98"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hello, I am trying to add a onclick or click event that will allow someone to input a city and retrieve said city's weather information. I had added a event listener to the api function however it does not seem to work. Please help?

Comment: Change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`. Type submit is actually submitting the form while triggering the `onclick` which is causing it to seem like the ajax isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few problems with your html and your js.
First with your js. In your file, all the code is in 'the main' and is being executed as soon as the file loads. You dont want that, you want to create a function so you can use it to link it with the 'onclick' event. You that simply by wrapping your code in a function like this:

```
function myfunction() {
    $.getJSON("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q="+City+"&appid=dc171ae0b3b507207c6605cbab0a5f98",
        function(data){
            console.log(data);
            
            var icon ="https://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.list[0].weather[0].icon +".png";
            var temp=Math.floor(data.list[0].main.temp);
            var weather=data.list[0].weather[0].main;
            var city=data.city.name;
            var date= data.list[0].dt_txt;
            var humidity=data.list[0].main.humidity;
            var wind=data.list[0].wind.speed;
            $(".icon").attr("src",icon);
            $(".weather").append(weather);
            $(".temp").append(temp);
            $(".city").append(city);    
            $(".date").append(date);
            $(".humidity").append(humidity);
            $(".wind").append(wind);
    });
}
```

After that, I see you've got a variable called City inside your request which has no value. Your code has to know what is that and be able to retrieve its value. For that we call the 'document' object which contains the input and take its value. Like this:

```
var City = document.getElementById('input').value;
console.log(City) // Print it for good meassure
```

With that inside your function, every time you click the button, the value is going to be updated and do the request.

Now, in your html you need to change your button's type property. If its of type submit, the form is submited and the page reloaded (The whole form is unnecesary really but I'll leave it in as to not change your code too much). In this case you want your button to be of type 'button' so it only acts as a button when pressed. Like this:

```
...
      <form class="searchInput" style="margin:auto;max-width:300px" >
        <input id="input" class="input1" type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="search">
        <button onclick="myfunction()" id="button" class="button1" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </form>
...
```

With all that your code should work, retrieve your json and display the information you want on screen.

I hope all of this helps!